# How to I make check marks appear and disappear when I click multiple rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

I want a table which, when you click different rows, they gain or lose a checkmark to show they are either selected or not selected.

Currently my tableview will let me select and deselect different rows. But a checkmark will only appear once I have clicked one and then another. The same happens when I deselect, I click a row with a checkmark then click another row and the checkmark disappears.

Here is my code currently:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * exerciseChoiceSimpleTableIdentifier = @"ExerciseChoiceSimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * exerciseChoiceCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:exerciseChoiceSimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (exerciseChoiceCell == nil) {
        exerciseChoiceCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:exerciseChoiceSimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    //Here we get each exercise we want to display
    BExercise * exercise = [[_data getExerciseCompleteList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Name the cell after the exercises we want to display
    exerciseChoiceCell.textLabel.text = exercise.name;

    return exerciseChoiceCell;
}

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        // Uncheck the row
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
    // Check the row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
}
```

I think the problem is to do with it being selected rather than touch up inside and deselecting when the finger is released from the button.

I am expecting the answer to be quite straight forward but all the similar questions on stackflow haven't dealt with the checkmarks delayed appearance.

It would be great to understand the root of this problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the method

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

by

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```